# How to write single quotes inside a double quotes in string inputted Html Elements

Tags: javascript, html, string, quotes

```
string mystring == "<input class=\"success\" type=\"button\" id=\"Delegate_New_btn\" value=\"New\" onclick=\"location.href="+mylocation+"'/>";
```

I have a string like above.

The problem is when I innerHTML it to a div like below, then it shows incorrect syntax error :

```
document.getElementById("id").innerHTML=mystring;
```

What I need is :

```
<input type="button" value"somevalue" onclick="location.href='mylocationurl'"/>
```

I don't know how to include this single quotes inside a double quotes. I had tried back slash method but I also failed to implement that.

Note : i had define this in my serverside C# and pass it to client side 
Please help me to solve this.

More information

```
VM.Custombuttons_tag = "<td><input class=\"btn btn-mini btn-success\" type=\"button\" id=\"Delegate_New_btn\" value=\"New\" onclick='location.href=\'" + string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, Url.Content("~")) + "/ABC/Delegate/AssignListUserLevel?PeriodId=0'/></td>";
```

this is my full code here VM is a method and Custombuttons_tag is string so when ever i run my code it will innerHTML the code to a div and it shows some incorrect syntax error

Comment: I don't think your problem has anything to do with double quotes. Not sure what you meant by this: "i had define this in my serverside C# and pass it to client side". By what means did you pass this to client side? Please show that code. Is the first line of code C#? For this `document.getElementById("id").innerHTML=string;`, where is `string` defined? Where is `mylocationurl` defined? Please provide all relevant code!

Answer (score 2):

You do not define a string using `string`, you define **everything** using `var`:

```
var myString = "I am a string";
var myNumber = 1000;
```

Java and JavaScript do have their differences!

Comment: your answer not apt for my situvation

Comment: also you can give an answer in javascript it will solve my problem then i can accept it

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like this ...

```
var input=document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('class','success');
input.setAttribute('type','button');
input.setAttribute('id','Delegate_New_btn');
input.setAttribute('value','New');
input.setAttribute('onclick','location.href="'+mylocation+'"');

document.getElementById('id').appendChild(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here, the first being that you do not use `==` when assigning variables, and the second being that you need to use `var` rather than `string`.

So, your code should look like this:
    `var mystring = "<input class='success' type='button' id='Delegate_New_btn' value='New' onclick='location.href=\'+mylocation+\''/>";`

The only time that you need to use `\'` is if your single quotes are included in single quotes, like you have with the `location.href` part.

Comment: mylocation is a predefined variable here so in your code it also takes as a string

Answer (score 0):

You can mix-match single and double quotes as long as they are nested properly.

```
var mystring = '<input class="success" type="button" id="Delegate_New_btn" value="New" onclick="location.href=' + mylocation + '"/>';
```

Comment: it will works in but in server side i can't start a string with single quotes

Comment: Then switch the double and single quotes around...it will still work in JS.

Comment: not it will not because when we innerHTML those all single quotes with out backslash will treated as double quotes

Comment: Don't use innerHTML then, do something like this `document.getElementById("id").html(mystring);`

Comment: Both are same in effect

Comment: Oh my bad about that, but I guess I don't understand what you mean when you say it will be treated as double/single quote? It shouldn't change anything in the variable. Can you post an example?